# Implementing a binary protocol in Python (twisted)

Tags: python, networking, twisted, binary-data

I've written a TCP server in node.js implementing a binary protocol.
Using buffers this was very easy in node.js.
http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.3/api/buffers.html

I'm looking for a similar way to implement my protocol in python 2.7 using twisted.
However, if there's a better tool for the job combining python 3 and some sort of evented I/O, please let me know. Because of bytes object in python 3, at first look it seams to me that python 3 is better at handling binary protocols. I need to handle many TCP(and UDP) connections and write a bit of GUI.

Here's how implement my protocol in node.js:

```
var buf = new Buffer(5+data.length),  //headers + data (data is also a buffer)
    action = 0x01;

buf[0] = action;
buf.writeUInt16(data.length,1,'big'); //write content length in at offset 1
buf.writeUint16(12345,5,'big');       //message identifier at offset 3
data.copy(buf,5);                     //copy data into message at offset 5

socket.write(buf);
```

I would appreciate examples for how to achieve similar instructions in python.

Edit: this is how I was able to implement my protocol using the python struct module:

```
self.transport.write(struct.pack('!bHH',action,data.length, sock_id) + data)
```

Comment: You may want to go the other way and implement an existing protocol in Node rather than inventing something completely custom.  AMP is a message-based protocol construction kit in Twisted that's designed to be very easy to work with in other systems.  See http://amp-protocol.net/ for work on making that a standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the standard Python [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module will do what you need. It allows you to specify exactly what the layout of binary data needs to be.

The capabilities of handling binary protocols in Python 2 and Python 3 are equivalent.

Comment: This is part of the answer, but not the whole answer.  Make sure you're aware of this Twisted FAQ: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Whyisprotocol.dataReceivedcalledwithonlypartofthedataIcalledtransport.writewith

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: your link seems dead: Subscription Expired

Answer (score 0):

If efficiency is of concern and you want to do stuff like i.e. XOR a whole chunk of bytes, you migh want to look at Python bytearray, which is a mutable array of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a bit more abstraction over the `struct` module, try [`protlib`](http://pythonhosted.org/protlib/). The nice thing is that you can deal with python objects out of the box instead of single fields.